# Как происходит обработка\вывод исключений из C++ CLI кода в C# коде?

Tags: c++-cli

Наверное, один из главных вопросов, которые остались - это как именно происходит обработка\вывод исключений из C++ CLI кода в C# коде.

Ведь С++ CLI совмещает в себе управляемый и неуправляемый код, и в добавок вызывается из управляемого C# кода.

Как на стороне C# правильно обрабатывать исключения C++ CLI кода:

- Если в управляемой части CLI кода не проставлены `try\catch` блоки из `<exception>`?
- Если в управляемой части CLI кода проставлены `try\catch` блоки из `<exception>`? Пробрасывать дальше?
- Если на стороне неуправляемого кода выбивает `AcсessViolation`, а в управляемой части CLI этот метод находится в блоке `try\catch` - приложение всеравно рухнет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бросание  исключений между библиотеками и языками следует исключить.

Причина - в C++ нет фиксированного ABI, даже разные версии компилятора могут внутри эти делишки реализовывать разными способами.

Хотите надежный и переносимый код - локализуйте исключения в пределах одного бинарника.